# Hide a C++ code block from Intellisense

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor, intellisense

In order to work around some Intellisense deficiencies in MSVC++ 2010, I would like to "hide" some code block from Intellisense, but not from the compiler. For example:

```
#ifndef INTELLISENSE
void foo(); // compiled, but skipped by Intellisense
#endif
```

I'm looking for the exact name of this `INTELLISENSE` macro, if such a macro exists; or an equivalent way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The proper macro for VC++ 2010 is `__INTELLISENSE__`, as described in this blog article: [Troubleshooting Tips for IntelliSense Slowness](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2011/03/29/troubleshooting-tips-for-intellisense-slowness/)

Comment: Indeed it is. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Rob Kennedy : MSFT considers official team blogs official documentation.