# Is there a macro defined when IntelliSense is parsing?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, macros, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Every compiler has a macro like `__BORLANDC__` defined that enables the programmer to activate or deactivate certain behaviour or workarounds.

Is such a macro defined while IntelliSense parses files so I can activate workarounds for bugs?

```
#if defined __INTELLISENSE__
#define SOMETHING
#endif
```

Comment: Hey cool, I didn't know you could use `defined` without parentheses. I learn something every day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide a C++ code block from Intellisense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496524/hide-a-c-code-block-from-intellisense)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. [It's called `__INTELLISENSE__`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/troubleshooting-tips-for-intellisense-slowness/), as you've guessed.

```
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
// ...
#endif
```